# How to integrate conda based python project with bazel

Tags: anaconda, bazel

I have a python project which uses anaconda as its Python distribution. What's the best way to convert it to bazel. I.e. how to do the following?:

- Install conda from the build script
- Install required libraries into this conda distribution
- Add dependencies on these libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used bazel repository rules for this: https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/repository_rules.html

Comment: Howdy Konstantin! Any chance you'd be able to share an example version of your rules?

Comment: Updated link: https://bazel.build/rules/repository_rules

Answer (score 1):

Here is an open-source set of rules for creating conda environments within a bazel build:
https://github.com/spietras/rules_conda

The following example code is copied from the README of that github repository. It demonstrates how to create a conda environment from a `@//:environment.yml` file:

> ```py
> load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")
>
> http_archive(
>     name = "rules_conda",
>     sha256 = "...",  # copy from release
>     url = "...",  # copy from release
> )
>
> load("@rules_conda//:defs.bzl", "conda_create", "load_conda", "register_toolchain")
>
> load_conda(
>     conda_version = "4.10.3",  # version of conda to download, default is 4.10.3
>     installer = "miniforge",  # which conda installer to download, either miniconda or miniforge, default is miniconda
>     install_mamba = True,  # whether to install mamba, which is a faster drop-in replacement for conda, default is False
>     mamba_version = "0.17.0",  # version of mamba to install, default is 0.17.0
>     quiet = False,  # True if conda output should be hidden, default is True
>     timeout = 600,  # how many seconds each execute action can take, default is 3600
> )
>
> conda_create(
>     name = "env",  # name of the environment
>     environment = "@//:environment.yml",  # label pointing to environment configuration file
>     use_mamba = True,  # Whether to use mamba to create the conda environment. If this is True, install_mamba must also be True
>     clean = False,  # True if conda cache should be cleaned (less space taken, but slower subsequent builds), default is False
>     quiet = False,  # True if conda output should be hidden   True, default is True
>     timeout = 600,  # how many seconds each execute action can take, default is 3600
> )
>
> register_toolchain(env = "env")
> ```